# Joining models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a gallery model with image and user id. On the gallery index i would like to show the image with the user name. How do I retrieve username with the user id in the gallery model?

my relationships are

`user has_many galleries`

`gallery belongs_to user`

I am getting the user id through a hidden field which captures current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gallery's `user` attribute :

```
<%= image_tag @gallery.user.image %>
```